# Overriding default mock property value

Tags: rhino-mocks

I am setting up a default mock object which I will then test a validation method by changing each one of the properties and verifying the error message.  The below test is false because the property ApprovalAmount is always 123.

IConfig configmock;
IDocument cerDocumentMock;

```
private void InitialSetup()
    {
        configMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IConfig>();
        cerDocumentMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDocument>();

        cerDocumentMock.Expect(x => x.ApprovalAmount).Return(123);
    }        

    [Fact]
    public void FailedUploadWithApprovalAmountBeingLessThanZero()
    {
        InitialSetup();
        cerDocumentMock.Expect(x => x.ApprovalAmount).Return(-1);
        CERServ = new CERService(cerDocumentMock, configMock);

        ExpectedString = "The approval amount must be greater than zero.<br/>";
        CERServ.Validate();

        Assert.Equal(ExpectedString, CERServ.Message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `InitialSetup` you set an expectation on `ApprovalAmount` and then you do it again in the test.  That means the first access to `ApprovalAmount` will return 123 and the second time its accessed it will return -1.

I don't think you need the first Expectation inside `InitialSetup`.

Comment: The initial one was there because I am setting up a group of values as default so I can test each one having invalid values.  I found that with newest version of rhino you can just set the property to a value instead of using expect.